# Page proportions off only on iPad

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

I have included two images using the iOS simulator in xcode, but this is also How it looks on an iPad turned portrait. In the first image you can see the bottom bar is cut off. The second has been scrolled down which is actually the starting position when this page is loaded on an iPad. Does anyone know why only the iPad would display like this when it is fine in browser (i.e., bars are attached to `top:0` and `bottom: 0` respectively)

here is the css for the bars.

```
.bars {
  -webkit-user-select: none;         
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select: none; 
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width:100%;
  left:0px;
  height:54px;
  box-shadow:0px 1px 4px #444;
  background:white;
  z-index:100; 
}

#top{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  min-width:0px;
}

#bottom{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It might have something to do with Safari's funky auto-hiding menu bar.

Comment: Mobile devices don't understand position: fixed; - http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/. You can try use position: absolute for every container - top, container, etc

Comment: @user338636 the page works perfectly on all phones with fixed menu items. But I'll give it a shot

Comment: Using absolute position on the top bar stops the menu from disconnecting but one of the bars is still always cut off